# Change menu item class attribute

Tags: 7, theming

How can one change drupal's default CSS classes? They are set in drupal's core and I don't find if there is any hook to change the #attribute entry of a menu item.

CSS classes are already set before the theme_menu_link hook call, the classes of defined in menu.inc. Is there a hook to alter these values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to this by theming, try implementing `hook_preprocess_menu_link(&$variables)` in your theme's template.php.

```
function MY_THEME_NAME_preprocess_menu_link(&$variables) {
  // the class array is here
  $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's just menu links you're after you can give [Menu Attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) a whirl.

Comment: I had a look at the code and they directly act at the database level by changing attributes values in the menu_link table... I am theming, I'd rather prefer a theming-oriented solution :/

Comment: There's nothing wrong acting at the database level. Using Menu attributes you can skip preprocessing.

Comment: @Julio Guerra Using Menu Attributes is encouraged because your users may later assign classes to other menu items.